# Koin mocking suspend function

Tags: testing, koin

Can anybody tell me if/how I can mock a supend funktion with koin test? The only thing I know so far is this behavior

```
declareMock<...> {
      given(..)).willReturn(...)
   }
```

but this doesn't work on `suspend fun()`. Is there anything similar to 'coEvery' in Mockk, or how can I do this?

Thanx in advance,

Wolfgang

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found out how it works. You just can use any other mocking framework and use `declare` with that mock like so:

```
var preferenceRepository = mockk<PreferenceRepository>()


    @Before
    fun before() {
        startKoin {
            androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
        }
        declare {
            factory { preferenceRepository }
        }
    }
```